# flask_sqlalchemy: why instance created by Model.query.filter_by().first() doesn't run __init__() in model

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a User model like this:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True
    # ...

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        pass
```

When the instance is created like:`user = User(username='john')`, the constructor is called successfully.

But if the instance is returned by `user = User.query.filter_by(username=john).first()`, the constructor won't be called anyway.

And I have checked that the instance returned by the query is an instance of User, so the constructor should be called when the query is done. Because to my understanding, the constructor is called every time when an instance is created.

**The question is**: why this happens and what to do to call `__init__` when the user is returned by the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran accross this same problem (constructor not being called), and reading through [SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/constructors.html), that's exactly how it's supposed to behave. When an instance is being created from a `Query` object, it doesn't call the `__init__` method. Instead, it calls methods marked as `reconstructor` (decorator).

To mark a method as reconstructor, declare a parameterless method and decorate it with the method from your `SQLAlchemy` instance:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):

    @db.reconstructor
    def reload(self):
        # Will be run when loading from a Query object
```

From the documentation:

> Any method may be tagged as the `reconstructor()`, even the `__init__` method. SQLAlchemy will call the reconstructor method with no arguments.

So, if your class has initialization code, or if you call `super()`, you can call your reconstructor from your `__init__`:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.reload()

    @db.reconstructor
    def reload(self):
        # Process data from model
```

That way, `reload()` will be called upon custom initialization **and** when queried.